# How to pass an object into phantom js page using async/await approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, phantomjs

Here is the script I run using 'node --harmony-async-await run'

I want to collect logs into 'logs' array. But the array is undefined inside await function.

```
const phantomjs = async ({ development, script }) => {
  const instance = await phantom.create()
  const page = await instance.createPage()
  const logs = []

  await page.property('onConsoleMessage', function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('Console:', msg)
    logs.push(msg) // => will be not executed. logs is undefined here
  })
  ....some other actions
}
```

How to pass msg into array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because `page.property` does not return a promise, it means that there is no meaning use `await page.propperty(xxx, function () {})`. so maybe you can try to wrap your `page.propperty` first